# Writing Python script to select point within cell

Tags: python, point, select

I have two features: points and grid cells (vector). I want to select a point within a grid cell (some cell do not have point) using python script and create a new feature layer with below conditions:

1. If no point in cell then leave as it is.
2. If only one point then pick that point.
3. If more than one point then calculate average point.

How can I achieve this task?

Comment: What software do you have available to use?  ESRI? QGIS? PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2):

If you have ArcGIS - you can do the following - use the arcpy.InterpolateShape_3d() tool to get the value of the raster for each point - then use the arcpy.Statistics_analysis() tools to get the mean value for each raster value.

Comment: Thanks for your advice ! points and grid cells both are vector actually.Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Then you just need to do an Intersect of the points with the polygons - then the statistics again to get what you want.  Same process, just different tools/approach.